# How to increase the _id by 1 in sqlite using content provider?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

I want to write this query with content provider?

```
    UPDATE table  SET _id = _id + 1 WHERE  _id >= 3 ;
```

Comment: Why don't you just make the `_id` column to auto increment? A quick example: `integer primary key autoincrement`.

Comment: The _id is already set to  autoincrement  but i need to add +1 to the existing id's starting from id=3 so that i can insert a new record with id=3 for sync purpose